# Problem solving a PDE using separation of variables and Fourier expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the heat equation:
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}$$
The boundary conditions are:
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}(x=0)=0$$
$$\int_0^1\theta (t,x)dx=0$$
$$\theta(t=0)=x-\frac{1}{2}$$

Solution:

We assume $\theta=\theta_1(x)\theta_2(t)$. Then they satisfy:
$$\frac{d \theta_2}{dt}=-\lambda \theta_2;\frac{d^2 \theta_1}{dx^2}=-\lambda \theta_1$$
which have solutions:
$$\theta_2(t)=A_2e^{-\lambda t}; \theta_1(x)=A_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$$
On plugging the first boundary condition, we get $B_1=0$. The $2^{nd}$ boundary condition gives $\sqrt{\lambda}=n\pi$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. I am having trouble using the third boundary condition. $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$ has a Fourier expansion consisting of only $\sin$ terms (apart from the constant $-\frac{1}{2}$) whereas LHS $\theta(t=0)$ has only $\cos$ terms. How do I equate them?

The final solution is $$\theta(x,t)=-4\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2\pi^2}e^{-(2k-1)^2\pi^2t}\cos((2k-1)\pi x)$$

Comment: it depends on the domain you are assuming for $x$. if it is only $x \in (0,1)$, then you can Fourier expand $|x|-1/2$ on $(-1,1)$ which will have only $\cos$ terms

Comment: Thanks. My domain is indeed (0,1). You can write that up as answer.

Comment: You have shown that any function on the form $\theta = Ae^{-n^2\pi^2 t}\cos(n\pi x)$ is a solution. Since the equaltion is linear the most general solution is a linear combination of these giving us: $\theta(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}\cos(n\pi x)$. To impose the conditions $\theta(0,x) = x-1/2$ you can multiply by $\cos(m\pi x)$ and integrate over $[0,1]$ to get $\int_0^1(x-1/2)\cos(m\pi x){\rm d}x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_0^1\cos(m\pi x)\cos(n\pi x){\rm d}x$. Only the  $n=m$ term will be non-zero which allows you to compute $a_m$.